# Rails 4: Turbolinks sends request twice and reloads the page

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.1, turbolinks

I am working on on a Ruby on Rails application using Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.0.

I have set up the app to use Turbolinks, which is causing an issue with AJAX links. When I click on a link that calls an AJAX function three things happen:
1. The AJAX call is made
2. The same link is reloaded
3. The application server runs all the requests twice.

How can I make these links function as standard AJAX links?

For reference, here is the relevant portion of my `GemFile`:

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Here is how I included the JavaScript libraries in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

And here is how I included the JavaScript files in the application layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Answer (score 8):

There might be 3 reasons:

- Your response status to that request is between 400 and 600
- Your response content type does not match `/^(?:text\/html|application\/xhtml\+xml|application\/xml)(?:;|$)/`
- The assets has changed in new page. 
  For example, you render a new page in a different layout which includes another js. When `data-turbolinks-track` is true, turbolinks will do a refreshment.

The 3 reasons can be got from source code below. When response gives doc body, it will show it, or it will refresh page.

```
fetchReplacement = (url, onLoadFunction, showProgressBar = true) ->
  ...
  xhr.onload = ->
    triggerEvent EVENTS.RECEIVE, url: url.absolute
    if doc = processResponse()
      reflectNewUrl url
      reflectRedirectedUrl()
      changePage extractTitleAndBody(doc)...
      manuallyTriggerHashChangeForFirefox()
      onLoadFunction?()
      triggerEvent EVENTS.LOAD
    else
      document.location.href = crossOriginRedirect() or url.absolute

processResponse = ->
  clientOrServerError = ->
    400 <= xhr.status < 600

  validContent = ->
    (contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'))? and
      contentType.match /^(?:text\/html|application\/xhtml\+xml|application\/xml)(?:;|$)/

  ...

  //here is the check
  if not clientOrServerError() and validContent()
    doc = createDocument xhr.responseText
    if doc and !assetsChanged doc
      return doc
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `:onsubmit => "false"` in your forms, and use click function to run your submits.